# library venom-bot show this error in node version 18

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, venom

bot for whatsapp bot, first I used 4.3.7 version and work good, after alawys how timeout 30000. I updated node to version 18 and venom-bot version 5.0.5 but show this error:

D:\bot-politica\newBot>node index.js
D:\bot-politica\newBot\node_modules\venom-bot\dist\controllers\check-up-to-date.js:7
const latest_version_1 = __importDefault(require("latest-version"));
^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\bot-politica\newBot\node_modules\latest-version\index.js from D:\bot-politica\newBot\node_modules\venom-bot\dist\controllers\check-up-to-date.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\bot-politica\newBot\node_modules\venom-bot\dist\controllers\check-up-to-date.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\bot-politica\newBot\node_modules\venom-bot\dist\controllers\check-up-to-date.js:7:42)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\bot-politica\newBot\node_modules\venom-bot\dist\controllers\init.js:4:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\bot-politica\newBot\node_modules\venom-bot\dist\index.js:30:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\bot-politica\newBot\index.js:2:14) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Node.js v18.16.0

This is my test code:

Comment: Where is your code? :))

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest 'latest-version' node module and try again.
It will work properly.